# What is meant by "tir de barriere"

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

I have some troubles understanding the following expression, from [this video](https://youtu.be/oW4OC42Bzxo?t=462):

> Beaucoup d’entre nous ici déjà on fait l’expérience du tir de barrière assassin (...)

Has it something to do with the barricades? I'm confused.

Comment: You must provide more context; the paragraph in which you found that phrase, the title of the book or article and what it is about. That might help someone determine better what is meant.

Comment: I already put the link on the video where I found the expression, starting at the moment where the author uses it.

Comment: "Tir de barrière" does not seem to be a common phrase, maybe Despentes meant "tir de barrages" and had a slip of tongue ?

Comment: That could be, it makes sense given what she's saying. I was curious because Despentes often uses slang expressions not easy to find on dictionaries.

Comment: it means the rejection of the ideals represented by the revolutionaries. The arguments thrown are like fences presented to the other party. something you cannot overcome. Assasin because they are meant to destroy the other that is rejected, to make it disapear from the reality. the explanation is given at 8:28 when it is said: 'Ils voudraient revenir au temps où ils pouvaient dire: Toi tu te caches, tu te tais, ta parole n'est pas politique' Where the idea that someone's speach is not political is very important in a country of free speach (or pretend to) It means you have no public existence.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a well known expression so my guess is that means shootings from guards located on prison camp fences.

Comment: Le sens profond peut être symbolique : j'établis une barrière autour de ma famille, de mon domaine, de mes croyances, de ma politique, de mes pensées, de ma vision de ma vie comme les états établissent des frontières. Si vous me ressemblez, vous pouvez entrer, si votre renommée est négative pour moi, si je ne vous comprends pas, si vous voulez me faire changer … alors je vous expulse, je proteste *par avance*, je ne veux surtout pas avoir affaire à vous. Si vous me voulez du bien ou même m'aider, je vous trouve intrusif et vous écarte de mon chemin en disant du mal de vous.  …

Comment: … Les mots peuvent être blessants, comme les manipulations mentales et le formatage social sont néfastes. Ils font beaucoup moins de vacarme que les fusils, ils sont beaucoup plus efficaces dans le temps. Une barrière, bien que plus petite qu'une frontière, est dans cette expression synonyme de rempart infranchissable par nature, les mortes sont les pensées, les idées, la joie de vivre.